# Ruby on Rails app with Nginx unreachable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm deploying my Ruby on Rails website on a remote server.

- I put my code in /var/www/[websitename]
- `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` is as follows:

worker_processes  1;

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /home/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@meraki/gems/passenger-5.2.0;
    passenger_ruby /home/tamer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0@meraki/wrappers/ruby;
    passenger_app_env development;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
server {
listen 80;
server_name http://[my external ip];

# Tell Nginx and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
root /var/www/[my directory]/public;
index index.html index.htm;

# Static assets are served from the mentioned root directory
location / {
    #  root /var/www/APPNAME/current;
    #  index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Port $server_port;
    # proxy_set_header X-Real-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
}
```

- Then, I ran `rails s -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000`

The code runs perfectly in my terminal.
However, the browser gives me "This site can’t be reached".

I get the same result with `passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000`

How can I fix this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after running `iptables -F` and restarting my rails appllication.

Comment: What does that do?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE
your are connecting to your passenger instance localhost:3000
you should be able to connect via http://localhost IE default port 80 I think this is what you desire.

listen 80; <- > proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;